# Heroku push doesn't update the GitHub repo

Tags: git, heroku

I set up a heroku account and when I do `git push heroku master`, heroku shows that I built, but my local GitHub doesn't update with my code changes.

In my settings I have the proper GitHub repo too. [Picture of my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhgyR.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to work.

You pushed to a remote called `heroku`, which is likely pointed at Heroku. You probably have *another* remote, possibly called `origin`, that you haven't pushed these update to yet. Heroku will never update GitHub for you.

However it looks like you've set up the GitHub integration within Heroku. [That works in the other direction, from GitHub to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration):

> Heroku integrates with GitHub to make it easy to deploy code living on GitHub to apps running on Heroku. When GitHub integration is configured for a Heroku app, Heroku can automatically build and release (if the build is successful) pushes to the specified GitHub repo.

This can be manual, in which case you need to click a button on the Heroku side to build, or [automatic](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys), in which case your push to (or merge into) the configured GitHub branch will automatically trigger a build on Heroku.